# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin^2 (\pi\sqrt{n^{2014} + n^{2012} + 1})$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I tried to use $\sin^2(\pi x) = \sin^2 (\pi x - \pi)$

So,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin^2 (\pi\sqrt{n^{2014} + n^{2012} + 1}) \\
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin^2 (\pi(\sqrt{n^{2014} + n^{2012} + 1} - 1)) \\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin^2 (\frac{\pi (n^{2014} + n^{2012})}{\sqrt{n^{2014} + n^{2012} + 1}})$$

And I got trouble on here, Thanks for any hint.

Comment: What makes you think this is a convergent sequence?

Comment: The effect of $+1$ on the square-root is $O(n^{-1007})$ so it has no effect on the limit.  Perhaps the Taylor series of $(1+n^{-2})^{1/2}$ tells you whether the full square-root is near an integer.

Comment: @Pspl   Because I saw a problem like this before and that was converge. 
so I tried solve this but I got trouble.

Comment: I think I need to find some Polynomial $f(n)$ which satisfies : 
$\lim_{n\to\infty} (\sqrt{n^{2014} + n^{2012} + 1} - f(n)) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: **this is not a complete answer** but a small collection of some partial results.

**First remark**

$$
\begin{gathered}
  \pi \sqrt {n^2  + n + 1}  = \pi n\left( {1 + \frac{{\text{1}}}
{n} + \frac{1}
{{n^2 }}} \right)^{1/2}  =  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = \pi n\left( {1 + \frac{1}
{{2n}} + o\left( {\frac{1}
{n}} \right)} \right) = \pi n + \frac{\pi }
{2} + o\left( 1 \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
this means that
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \sin ^2 \left( {\pi \sqrt {n^2  + n + 1} } \right) = \sin ^2 \left( {\pi n + \frac{\pi }
{2} + o\left( 1 \right)} \right) =  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = \sin ^2 \left( {\frac{\pi }
{2} + o\left( 1 \right)} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
and therefore
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left[ {\sin ^2 \left( {\pi \sqrt {n^2  + n + 1} } \right)} \right] = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left[ {\sin ^2 \left( {\frac{\pi }
{2} + o\left( 1 \right)} \right)} \right] = 1
$$
This prove that, in general, it is not enough to consider only the main term of the polynomial under the square root.

**Second remark**
Let us consider a more general case

$$
\begin{gathered}
  \pi \sqrt {n^{2k}  + n^k  + 1}  = \pi n^k \left( {1 + \frac{{\text{1}}}
{{n^k }} + \frac{1}
{{n^{2k} }}} \right)^{1/2}  =  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = \pi n^k \left( {1 + \frac{1}
{{2n^k }} + o\left( {\frac{1}
{{n^k }}} \right)} \right) = \pi n^k  + \frac{\pi }
{2} + o\left( 1 \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
and as before we have that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left[ {\sin ^2 \left( {\pi \sqrt {n^{2k}  + n^k  + 1} } \right)} \right] = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left[ {\sin ^2 \left( {\frac{\pi }
{2} + o\left( 1 \right)} \right)} \right] = 1
$$
On the other side, if we consider $n^{2k}+n^h+1$ with $0 \leq h<k$ we have that
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \pi \sqrt {n^{2k}  + n^h  + 1}  = \pi n^k \left( {1 + \frac{{\text{1}}}
{{n^{2k - h} }} + \frac{1}
{{n^{2k} }}} \right)^{1/2}  =  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = \pi n^k \left( {1 + \frac{{\text{1}}}
{{2n^{2k - h} }} + o\left( {\frac{{\text{1}}}
{{n^{2k - h} }}} \right)} \right) = \pi n^k  + \frac{\pi }
{{2n^{k - h} }} + o\left( {\frac{1}
{{n^{k - h} }}} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
thus
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left[ {\sin ^2 \left( {\pi \sqrt {n^{2k}  + n^k  + 1} } \right)} \right] = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left[ {\sin ^2 \left( {\frac{\pi }
{{2n^{k - h} }} + o\left( {\frac{1}
{{n^{k - h} }}} \right)} \right)} \right] = 0
$$
**Third remark**:
My conjecture about the case $k<h<2k$ is motivated by numerical trials like  that below which is relative to the case $n^{20}+n^{18}+1$
[image]
I have some ideas but not yet a proof. Of course, if my conjecture is true the proposed limit does not exists.

**Fourth remark**:
Let be $h=k+1$ with $k \geq 3$. Then

$$
\begin{gathered}
  \pi \sqrt {n^{2k}  + n^{k + 1}  + 1}  = \pi n^k \left( {1 + \frac{{\text{1}}}
{{n^{k - 1} }} + \frac{1}
{{n^{2k} }}} \right)^{1/2}  =  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = \pi n^k \left( {1 + \frac{{\text{1}}}
{{2n^{k - 1} }} - \frac{1}
{{8n^{2k - 2} }} + o\left( {\frac{1}
{{n^{2k - 2} }}} \right)} \right) =  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = \pi n^k  + \frac{{\pi n}}
{2} - \frac{1}
{{8n^{k - 2} }} + O\left( {\frac{1}
{{n^{k - 2} }}} \right) \hfill \\
   \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \sin ^2 \left( {\pi \sqrt {n^{2k}  + n^{k + 1}  + 1} } \right) = \sin ^2 \left( {\pi \sqrt {n^{2k}  + n^{k + 1}  + 1} } \right) \hfill \\
   = \sin ^2 \left( {\pi n^k  + \frac{{\pi n}}
{2} - \frac{1}
{{8n^{k - 2} }} + O\left( {\frac{1}
{{n^{k - 2} }}} \right)} \right) =  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = \sin ^2 \left( {\frac{{\pi n}}
{2} - \frac{1}
{{8n^{k - 2} }} + O\left( {\frac{1}
{{n^{k - 2} }}} \right)} \right) \hfill \\
   \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
so that the limit does not exists.

Comment: Great! I'm gonna explore this just for the fun of it!

Comment: As soon as possible I will try to use more terms in the development of the square root. Right from now I'm quite sure that another term suffices to prove that the limit does not exists in the case $n^2k+n^k+1$ but I need time to write the complete proof of this case. Later I'll try to examine the full cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following argument is correct:

Imagine the sequence $u_n=\sin (\pi \sqrt{n^2+1}).$

It's easy to understand that $\lim_{n\to \infty}u_n=0$.

You can see it on the next representation of $u_n$:

[image: u representation]

That's because, when $n \to \infty$, you have $n^2+1 \sim n^2$ and you may write:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin (\pi \sqrt{n^2+1})=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin (\pi \sqrt{n^2})=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin (\pi n)=\lim_{n\to \infty}0=0$$

A similar argument may prove you that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin^2 (\pi\sqrt{n^{2014} + n^{2012} + 1})=0$, since $\sqrt{n^{2014} + n^{2012} + 1} \sim n^{1007}$ (when $n \to \infty$) which is always a natural number.

If there is a flaw on my argument, please let me know and I will delete this answer.

**EDIT:**

Actually, you **can** evaluate this using just the limits properties:

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin^2 (\pi\sqrt{n^{2014} + n^{2012} + 1})&=\sin^2 \left( \lim_{n\to\infty}(\pi\sqrt{n^{2014} + n^{2012} + 1}) \right)\\
&=\sin^2 \left(\pi \lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n^{2014} + n^{2012} + 1}) \right)\\
&=\sin^2 \left(\pi \sqrt{\lim_{n\to\infty}(n^{2014} + n^{2012} + 1}) \right)\\
&=\sin^2 \left(\pi \sqrt{\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{2014} } \right)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \;\;\;\;\;(1)\\
&=\sin^2 \left(\pi \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n^{2014} } \right)\\
&=\sin^2 \left(\pi \lim_{n\to\infty}{n^{1007} } \right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sin^2 \left(\pi {n^{1007} } \right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(0^2\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0\\
\end{align*}$$

I used approximation before to justifying a known theorem $(1)$:

> If $f(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+ ... +a_n$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a_0\neq0$, then:
>   $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}a_0x^n$$

which you use on the simplifications above.

Comment: This is one of reason which make me this limit converge, But I cannot find ways to solve this without approximation.

Comment: Your argument is correct. However, in this problem one needs to look at the fractional part of $n^{1006}\sqrt{n^2+1}$, while the fractional part of $\sqrt{n^2+1}$ tends to $0$, the fractional part of $n^{1006}\sqrt{n^2+1}$ may not do the same.

Comment: @bFur4list, please take a look at the edited part of my answer.

Comment: @Pspl No, now what you added in the edit is not correct. The 'justification' of (1) is wrong. The two limits in the highlighted part are not finite and you want to compose these limits with $\sin$, which doesn't have a (unique) limit at $\infty$.

Comment: @tora, maybe you're right. But, at least, show us that, if the limit exists, is for sure equal to $0$.

Comment: @Pspl No, it doesn't. The step (1) is just wrong. The fractional part of $\sqrt{n^{2012}}$ doesn't tell you anything about that of $\sqrt{n^{2014}+n^{2012}+1}$.

Comment: $n^2+n+1$ is also asymptotic to $n^2$ but in this case the limit is $1$ and not zero. It is easy to see way.  $
\pi \sqrt {n^2  + n + 1}  = \pi n\left( {1 + \frac{1}
{{2n}} + o\left( {\frac{1}
{n}} \right)} \right)
$
thus $
\pi \sqrt {n^2  + n + 1}  = \pi n + \frac{\pi }
{2} + o(1)
$
and therefore $
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \sin ^2 \left( {\pi \sqrt {n^2  + n + 1} } \right) = 1
$

Comment: My conjecture is that if we have a polynomial of the kind $n^{2k}+n^h+1$ as argument of the square root and $0 \leq h < k$ the limit is $0$. With $h=k$ the limit is $1$ while with $k<h\leq 2k-2$ the limit does not exists. Numerical trials seem to mach this conjecture but so far I'm only able to prove the first part.

Comment: @LucaGoldoniPh.D., your argument is very (much) interesting. Can you formalize it on an answer? Maybe with some more details?

Comment: I posted some quantitative remarks not yet a complete proof.